# Why does my server require an SSL handshake on certain jpeg images and not others?

Tags: https, images, page-speed

I am wondering why does my server require an SSL handshake on certain jpeg images and not others?

I have about 16 images on a page and it always seems like the 2nd 4th and 5th image require a handshake. All of the images are around the same size. Usually the ones that require are handshake are smaller than some of the others.

I am confused.

Comment: May be a silly question, but are you hosting all the images?  They aren't external are they?

Comment: Provide URLs to your images (both cases) and people will be able to troubleshoot things.